# shared preferences is throughing Exception

Tags: android

i am getting this problem and do not know how to find this out and I am also adding code where I getting this

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:376)
            at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:371)
            at com.example.mine4.accelerometergpsmaster.MainApplication.onPreferenceChange(MainApplication.java:100)
            at com.example.mine4.accelerometergpsmaster.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:108)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1259)
            at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2973)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
 public static void onPreferenceChange() {
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainApplication.getInstance());
        //  Get latest settings, and update accordingly
        boolean newState = sp.getBoolean("pref_onoff", false); // false is off/not-running

        prefInterval = Integer.parseInt( sp.getString("pref_interval", "60") );
        prefTimeout = Integer.parseInt( sp.getString("pref_timeout", "30") );

        MainApplication.prefThreshold = Double.parseDouble( sp.getString("pref_threshold", "0.30") );
        MainApplication.prefThreshold2 = MainApplication.prefThreshold + 9.80;

        // If we turned off the service, handle that change
        toggleState( newState );
    }
```

now please help me out for setting this problem

Comment: please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: u r not using Editor editor = sp.edit();

Comment: Please point these lines: `MainApplication.java:100` & `MainActivity.java:108`.

Comment: 100== sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainApplication.getInstance());

Comment: 108 is MainApplication.onPreferenceChange(); calling in main Activity

Answer (score 1):

I think it because MainApplication.getInstance() is null.
maybe you forgot to assign value for MainApplication.getInstance() or onPreferenceChange was called before the assigned code.

Comment: Yep. Looking at the crashing code, the only thing that could throw a `NullPointerException` would be `MainApplication.getInstance()` returning `null`: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java#L373